# How to make a plot from table data?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

Having the following table:

[image]

How can we make a plot diagram showing the relation between P,Q? I would like the P-value on y-axis and the Q-values on the x-axis.

Comment: The package pgfplotstable can do the job

Comment: As Marco pointed out, [`pgfplotstable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) can do this right out of the box; it is especially convenient when you have the raw data as a CSV file.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's a minimal example:

Assuming you have the data in a file (I called the file `data.dat`):

```
P $Q_A$ $Q_B$ $Q_D$
10 5 7 12
8 8 10 18
6 12 16 28
```

Use the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset{data.dat}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=Q Series,
  ylabel=P Values]
\addplot table [y=P, x=$Q_A$]{data.dat};
\addlegendentry{$Q_A$ series}
\addplot table [y=P, x=$Q_B$]{data.dat};
\addlegendentry{$Q_B$ series}
\addplot table [y=P, x=$Q_D$]{data.dat};
\addlegendentry{$Q_D$ series}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Check out the documentation for `pgfplots`.  It's very well suited to creating graphs.  I've only demonstrated the most basic possibilities.  But it has a lot of power.

*Note* if you're going to use the package `pgfplotstable` then, technically, there's no need to load `pgfplots`.  But, if you don't use `pgfplotstable` then be sure to load `pgfplots` to be able to graph your data.