# How to plot data in latex like Libreoffice calc?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I want to plot the following data in latex :

[image]

I have plotted it with libreoffice calc 5 on LinuxMint and look like below:

[image]

I want to do the same task with latex(tikzpicture)? I have tried to do this from the code given here : [How to make a plot from table data?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121750/how-to-make-a-plot-from-table-data),

but failed. How can I do this please help

**Added :**

Here's a minimal example:

I called the file data.dat:

```
P $Q_B$ $Q_C$ $Q_D$
A1  2   6   7
A2  3   65  87
A3  1   45  65
A4  4   54  45
A5  6   56  34
A6  8   34  23
A7  9   45  45
A8  13  23  56
A9  4.6 6   87
A10 4   56  89
```

Use the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

 %\pgfplotstabletypeset{data.dat}

 \vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=Q Series,
  ylabel=P Values]
\addplot table [y=P, x=$Q_B$]{data.dat};
\addlegendentry{$Q_B$ series}
\addplot table [y=P, x=$Q_C$]{data.dat};
\addlegendentry{$Q_C$ series}
\addplot table [y=P, x=$Q_D$]{data.dat};
\addlegendentry{$Q_D$ series}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @JosephWright I have updated my post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some explanation

1. Your first row is a string type. So you have to say this.
2. You need a floating point number for x. So I added an extra row.
3. By default not all xticks are shown. The default width of a pgfplot is 240pt. If you want to show all use the option `xtick=data`.

The example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
X P $Q_B$ $Q_C$ $Q_D$
1 A1  2   6   7
2 A2  3   65  87
3 A3  1   45  65
4 A4  4   54  45
5 A5  6   56  34
6 A6  8   34  23
7 A7  9   45  45
8 A8  13  23  56
9 A9  4.6 6   87
10 A10 4   56  89
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/P/.style={string type}]{data.dat}

 \vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=Q Series,
  ylabel=P Values,
  xticklabels from table={data.dat}{P},xtick=data]
\addplot[blue,thick,mark=square*] table [y=$Q_B$,x=X]{data.dat};
\addlegendentry{$Q_B$ series}
\addplot[red,thick,mark=square*] table [y=$Q_C$,x=X]{data.dat};
\addlegendentry{$Q_C$ series}
\addplot[black,dashed,thick,mark=square*]  table [y=$Q_D$,x=X]{data.dat};
\addlegendentry{$Q_D$ series}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you tell me please why labels $A_1, A_2$ are not showing below x-axis?

Comment: You are missing `xtick = {1,...,10},` --- otherwise some tick is optimized away (and arguably that could be a bug...).

Comment: @Rmano@Primo: It's not a bug. It's a predefined setting. You can change this by options.

Comment: Yep --- but the point at A10 is marked A7 in your graph.

Comment: @Rmano: New picture ;-)

Comment: @Primo: New version

Comment: Great. Deleted my answer!